# How can you make a micropython program on a raspberry pi pico autorun?

Tags: micropython, thonny, raspberry-pi-pico

I have used the software Thonny to send programs to my **raspberry pi pico**. I am trying to make a specific program auto run when my pico is plugged in. At the moment another program which is on the pico auto runs but I want another program to run instead.

Comment: Name the script `main.py` to make it run on power-up.

Answer (score 5):

Name the program you want to run main.py

Comment: Nice concise answer, I would add ... create a simple, hardened main.py that runs your program. I loathe multiple projects, all with a generic main.py. Its just me.

Answer (score 2):

Tested on Rpi Pico W, Ubuntu 22.04 host.

**Command line approach**

1. Install the MicroPython firmware.

   1. Download the latest prebuilt firmware, it is a UF2 file:

      - non-W: https://micropython.org/download/rp2-pico/
      - W: https://micropython.org/download/rp2-pico-w/
   2. Plug the Pi USB to computer while holding the BOOTSEL button.

      A filesystem should appear on host.
   3. Copy the file into the filesystem. On Ubuntu it automounts something like:

      ```
      cp ~/Downloads/rp2-pico-w-20221014-unstable-v1.19.1-544-g89b320737.uf2 /media/$USER/RPI-RP2/
      ```
   4. When flashing ends, the filesystem automatically unmounts, leaving you in non-boot mode. The firmware has been installed.
2. Install your program as `main.py` on the board.

   1. Ensure the board is not in boot mode:

   - after installing firmware, this happens automatically
   - otherwise just unplug the USB and plug it back in without holding the BOOTSEL button

   1. Install `rshell` on host:

      ```
      python3 -m pip install --user rshell
      ```
   2. Copy your program to the board as `main.py`. Supposing you have a blinker program at `blink.py` in the current working directory, run:

      `rshell -p /dev/ttyACM0 --buffer-size 512 cp blink.py /pyboard/main.py`

      `/pyboard` is a magic path to rshell, not actually present on the host. Terrible API!!!

      This is what I tested with:

      ```
      import machine
      import time

      led = machine.Pin('LED', machine.Pin.OUT)
      # For Rpi Pico (non-W) it was like this instead apparently.
      # led = Pin(25, Pin.OUT)

      while (True):
          led.on()
          time.sleep(.5)
          led.off()
          time.sleep(.5)
      ```

      The `main.py` thing is documented e.g. at: https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/getting-started-with-the-pico/9
   3. Unplug and replug the USB without holding BOOTSEL. Every time you do this, the `main.py` program starts running automatically.

After installing, you can also use `rshell` to check the contents of `main.py` with:

```
rshell -p /dev/ttyACM0 --buffer-size 512 cat /pyboard/main.py
```

Bibliography:

- https://forum.micropython.org/viewtopic.php?t=3610
- https://forum.micropython.org/viewtopic.php?t=6005
- https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=301927

**Thonny editor UI approach**

This is the procedure described on the official docs at: https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/getting-started-with-the-pico/0

It does the same steps as the CLI approach, but as usual with UIs making it more obscure what is actually happening behind the scenes :-)

1. Install Thonny:

   ```
   python3 -m pip install --user thonny
   ```
2. Install the MicroPython firmware

   1. Plug the Pico while holding BOOTSEL
   2. Open Thonny from the command line:

      ```
      thonny
      ```

      I tested with version 4.0.1.
   3. Click Python version on bottom right of the screen (bad UI)
   4. Install MicroPython
   5. MicroPython variant: Raspberry Pi Pico (choose W vs non W)
   6. Install
   7. Unplug the Pico, close Thonny, replug the Pico without BOOTSEL, reopen Thonny
3. Install your program as `main.py` on the board

   1. Paste our `blink.py` on the main Thonny editor window
   2. File > Save (or Ctrl + S)
   3. A popup opens, choose: "Raspberry Pi Pico" (instead of "This computer")
   4. Save the file as `main.py` on the Pico
   5. Unplug USB and replug. `main.py` starts running.

Comment: A "Let there be light" response - the OP stated he was using Thonny already, just name the main program main.py.