# Raspberry Pico W MicroPython execution freezes a few seconds after disconnecting screen from UART

Tags: micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I got my program running fine as explained at: [How can you make a micropython program on a raspberry pi pico autorun?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66183596/how-can-you-make-a-micropython-program-on-a-raspberry-pi-pico-autorun/74078142#74078142)

I'm installing a `main.py` that does:

```
import machine
import time

led = machine.Pin('LED', machine.Pin.OUT)
# For Rpi Pico (non-W) it was like this instead apparently.
# led = Pin(25, Pin.OUT)

i = 0
while (True):
    led.toggle()
    print(i)
    time.sleep(.5)
    i += 1
```

When I power the device on by plugging the USB to my laptop, it seems to run fine, with the LED blinking.

Then, if I connect from my laptop to the UART with:

```
screen /dev/ttyACM0 115200
```

I can see the numbers coming out on my host terminal correctly, and the LED still blinks, all as expected.

However, when I disconnect from screen with Ctrl-A K, after a few seconds, the LED stops blinking! It takes something around 15 seconds for it to stop, but it does so every time I tested.

If I reconnect the UART again with:

```
screen /dev/ttyACM0 115200
```

it starts blinking again.

Also also noticed that after I reconnect the UART and execution resumes, the count has increased much less than the actual time passed, so one possibility is that the Pico is going into some slow low power mode?

If I remove the `print()` from the program, I noticed that it does not freeze anymore after disconnecting the UART (which of course shows no data in this case).

`screen -fn`, `screen -f` and `screen -fa` made no difference.

Micropython firmware: rp2-pico-w-20221014-unstable-v1.19.1-544-g89b320737.uf2, Ubuntu 22.04 host.

Some variants follow.

`picocom /dev/ttyACM0` instead of screen and disconnect with Ctrl-A Ctrl-Q: still freezes like with `screen`.

If I exit from `picocom` with Ctrl-A Ctrl-X instead however, then it works. The difference between both seems to be that Ctrl-Q logs:

```
Skipping tty reset...
```

while Ctrl-X doesn't, making this a good possible workaround.

The following C analog of the MicroPython hacked from:

- https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-examples/blob/a7ad17156bf60842ee55c8f86cd39e9cd7427c1d/pico_w/blink
- https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-examples/blob/a7ad17156bf60842ee55c8f86cd39e9cd7427c1d/hello_world/usb

did not show the same problem, tested on https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-sdk/tree/2e6142b15b8a75c1227dd3edbe839193b2bf9041

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "pico/stdlib.h"
#include "pico/cyw43_arch.h"

int main() {
    stdio_init_all();
    if (cyw43_arch_init()) {
        printf("WiFi init failed");
        return -1;
    }
    int i = 0;
    while (true) {
        printf("%i\n", i);
        cyw43_arch_gpio_put(CYW43_WL_GPIO_LED_PIN, i % 2);
        i++;
        sleep_ms(500);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Reproduction speed can be greatly increased from a few seconds to almost instant by printing more and faster as in:

```
import machine
import time

led = machine.Pin('LED', machine.Pin.OUT)

i = 0
while (True):
    led.toggle()
    print('asdf ' * 10 + str(i))
    time.sleep(.1)
    i += 1
```

This corroborates people's theories that the problem is linked to flow control: the sender appears to stop sending if the consumer stops being able to receive fast enough.

Also asked at:

- https://github.com/orgs/micropython/discussions/9633

Possibly related:

- https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?p=1833725&hilit=uart+freezes#p1833725

Comment: If you remove the `print` statement from the `while` loop, does it continue to run correctly after disconnecting your `screen` session?

Comment: @larsks tested now, removing the `print()` does make it not get stuck anymore after closing `screen`

Comment: It *sounds* like the serial port is behaving as if it's still open and is ultimately activating some sort of flow control because nothing is reading the incoming data. If you use something other than `screen` (e.g., `picocom`, etc), do you see the same behavior?

Comment: @larsks `picocom /dev/ttyACM0` and disconnect with Ctrl-A Ctrl-Q also froze like with `screen`.

Comment: @larsks exiting picocom with Ctral-A Ctrl-X does work however!

Answer (score 1):

What appears to be happening here is that exiting `screen` (or exiting `picocom` without the tty reset) leaves the [`DTR`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Terminal_Ready) line on the serial port high. We can verify this by writing some simple code to control the DTR line, like this:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <signal.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int fd;

    int dtrEnable;
    int flags;

    if (argc < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ioctl <device> <1 or 0 (DTR high or low)>\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((fd = open(argv[1], O_RDWR | O_NDELAY)) < 0) {
        perror("open:");
        exit(1);
    }

    sscanf(argv[2], "%d", &dtrEnable);

    ioctl(fd, TIOCMGET, &flags);

    if(dtrEnable!=0) {
        flags |= TIOCM_DTR;
    } else {
        flags &= ~TIOCM_DTR;
    }


    ioctl(fd, TIOCMSET, &flags);

    close(fd);
}
```

Compile this into a tool called `setdtr`:

```
gcc -o setdtr setdtr.c
```

Connect to your Pico using `screen`, start your code, and then disconnect. Wait for the LED to stop blinking. Now run:

```
./setdtr /dev/ttyACM0 0
```

You will find that your code starts running again. If you run:

```
./setdr /dev/ttyACM0 1
```

You will find that your code gets stuck again.

---

The serial chip on the RP2040 interprets a high DTR line to mean that a device is still connected. If nothing is reading from the serial port, it eventually blocks. Setting the DTR pin to 0 -- either using this `setdtr` tool or by explicitly resetting the serial port state on close -- avoids this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it works, but based on advie from larsks:

```
sudo apt install picocom
picocom /dev/ttyACM0
```

and then quit with Ctrl-A Ctrl-X (not Ctrl-A Ctrl-Q) does do what I want. Not sure what `screen` is doing differently exactly.

When quitting, Ctrl-Q shows on terminal:

```
Skipping tty reset...
```

and Ctrl-X does not, which may be a major clue.